# Why has the .NET Core WinForms designer stopped working in VS2019?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core

### What I am trying to do

I have a .NET Core 3.1 WinForms project. I am trying to open the designer view in Visual Studio 2019.

### Problem

When I open the designer for my form in the solution explorer, it opens a preview of some random default component, not my form that I have designed. It's just displaying an empty window, like how the form looks in a new project. See the screenshots below.

My form when running the project:
[image]

The random form being displayed in the design viewer:
[image]

### Question and Other Notes

The strange thing is, the designer worked a few days ago, the first day I created the project and designed the form. Today the design preview randomly stopped working.

What is causing this?

Comment: I've seen weird bugs like this, but usually I can resolve them by closing Visual Studio and then deleting all the temp folders from the project, i.e "/bin", "/obj" and ".vs".

Comment: I also had to clear some cache, once. But that was on an older version and dotnet Framework.

Comment: Can anyone solve this problem? When we click view designer in visual studio 2019, blank form is appear with grey color, without any component within that.

Comment: I was testing a form and put an extra class in front of my `public partial class MainForm : Form`. The designer stopped working. I removed the class so that `public partial class MainForm : Form` was first and it worked again.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/main/docs/winforms-designer.md "but it is currently available as a pre-release Visual Studio extension." So you shouldn't expect too much.

Answer (score -2):

now it is working. and whenever it crashes u will have to edit your cproj file and remove that stupid trial version line from there and the designer shall work fine.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.